# Get all folders with photo - Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

```
String albumName = albumTitle; 
String ExternalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/My_Albums/" + albumName;
    File targetDirectory = new File(ExternalStorageDirectory);
    if (targetDirectory != null) {
        File[] files = targetDirectory.listFiles();     
        if (files != null) {
            filePathString = new String[files.length];
            fileNameString = new String[files.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                filePathString[i] = files[i].getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println("filePAthStr: " + filePathString[i]);
                fileNameString[i] = files[i].getName();
                System.out.println("fileNameStr: " + fileNameString[i]);
                customGridAdapter.add(filePathString[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

1. How do I get all folders with photo.
2. How do I get media from mediastore efficiently

Comment: Can you post snap for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intially , album name will be empty

`String albumName = albumTitle;`

So if you aint enter the album name, the path would be like

```
String ExternalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/My_Albums/";
```

it will go the parent path ,get all the albums under that node and display the number of images under it.
when once you provide albumname,it will get all images inside it and displays.In this scenario you need to loop inside album to cover each and every album under it and get the image paths from them.

**UPDATE**

For implementing this Logic refer link : [Get All Folders With Photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686024/android-how-to-get-all-folders-with-photos)

Comment: i've Updated .check once

Comment: Cant i have any condition that if albumName is null it shout not proceed further ....

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, which was quite simple.

if(albumName != null && !albumName.equals("")){

// Only then set the adapter

}